# Save EVObjects with CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, multiple-inheritance

I need to save some data with CoreData. Generally thats not a problem at all. The problem is, that the data is created with EVReflection an therefore inherits the class EVObject. To save the gathered data to CoreData they have to also inherit NSManagedObject. The problem is that swift does not allow you to inherit multiple classes. Would appreciate any tips.

```
class Device : EVObject
{
    var channel : [Channel] = [Channel]()
    var name : String = ""
    var ise_id : Int = 0
    var unreach : Bool = false
    var sticky_unreach : Bool = false
    var config_pending : Bool = false

    override internal func propertyMapping() -> [(String?, String?)] {
        return [("name", "_name"), ("ise_id", "_ise_id"), ("unreach", "_unreach"), ("sticky_unreach", "_sticky_unreach"), ("config_pending", "_config_pending")]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to inherit. You can extend them. Example:

```
class User : NSManagedObject{
   @NSManaged .....
}

//Extension
import EVReflection
extension User : EVReflectable { }
```

https://github.com/evermeer/EVReflection#extending-existing-objects

Answer (score 0):

Note I'm not aware of EVReflection but I think this answer can generally apply.

Don't use multiple inheritance. Have two separate classes and a mechanism for creating/loading/updating one object from the other. Protocols may allow it to be done in a way that minimises translation boilerplate (possibly using `valueForKey(_:)` and `setValue(_:forKey)` if you can know the key names in a safe manner.

It may not even be even be necessary to have an NSManagedObject subclass but just have an instance of NSManagedObject in all your classes that is loaded/created/saved as necessary.

Comment: So I have to create a new class and than map the actions between them ?
That seems really inconvenient. I would have to download some xml data to one class and than copy the data to a class that has the same properties just to save it on the persistent storage. I just added the class that EVReflection uses to create objects from xml.

Comment: It seems like not using NSManagedObject at all is the best way, but I can't get the relations in the data model to work ...

Comment: You don't have to subclass NSManagedObject but you can have an instance in your EVObject. If you don't like the KVC (`valueForKey`, `setValueForKey`) you can generate the NSManagedObject classes from the data model. You still have an instance attached to your main object that it can use to store/load from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what functionality you want to use from EVReflection. Since NSManagedObject also has NSObject as it's base class you could use most functions by just setting NSManagedObject as your base class instead of EVObject.

The only thing you have to do is instead of calling EVObject functions directly, you have to implement the code snippets that are in that EVObject method. Almost any function there is just a convenience method that will call the corresponding EVReflection function.

If you have any questions in the future, then please also report this as an issue on GitHub.